# Rewriting an expression for a line

Tags: linear-algebra

I got an expression:
$ \frac{x}{2} = 2y = z +1 $ that I want on the form: $\alpha x + \beta x + \gamma z + D = 0 $

I know that $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ is $4,1,2$ but I don't get that rewrite.

My tries are:
$ \frac{x}{2} = 2y = z +1 \Leftrightarrow x -1 = 4y = 2z +2 \Leftrightarrow x -1 -4y = 2z +2 -4y \Leftrightarrow x + 0y -2z -1 = 0 $

Comment: Where did you find this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You start with something that is a line in $\mathbb R^3$ and you finish with something that is a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. Something is wrong in your statement.

Maybe you want to obtain an intersection of two planes?

Comment: I got a vector $u = (1,-1,1)$ and I want to express that in effective components which one of them is parallell to the line $\frac{x-1}{2} = 2y = z+1$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. What exactly did you mean for " *which one of them* "?

Comment: sorry it should been with. One of the components are parallell to the line, the other is ortogonal.

Comment: So do you want to write the equation of a line in $\mathbb R^3$ that is perpendicular to the vector $u=(1,-1,1)$ and parallel to the line $(2(t+1), t/2, t-1)$? This is impossible. If not please edit your question, and write down each detail.

Comment: Sorry I make a typo mistake the line coming from the relations written by you is the following: $(2t,t/2,t-1)$.